# How to disable Automake docs?

Tags: configuration, autoconf, automake

I'm trying to update Automake on a really old CentOS machine. The build is failing with:

```
$ make -j 4
...

  MAKEINFO doc/automake.info
/home/scripts/automake-1.15.1/lib/missing: line 81: makeinfo: command not found
WARNING: 'makeinfo' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified a '.texi' file, or
         any other file indirectly affecting the aspect of the manual.
         You might want to install the Texinfo package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/>
         The spurious makeinfo call might also be the consequence of
         using a buggy 'make' (AIX, DU, IRIX), in which case you might
         want to install GNU make:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/make/>
gmake: *** [Makefile:2518: doc/automake.info] Error 127
```

Building the docs is not a requirement. In fact it is unwanted because it is another point of failure and it takes up space on some devices that only have a couple hundred MB free.

According to `configure --help` we can disable them with `--disable-FEATURE`. The problem is, I don't know the feature name. I tried the obvious ones like:

- `--disable-doc`
- `--disable-docs`
- `--disable-texi`
- `--disable-texinfo`
- `--disable-DOCDIR`
- `--disable-automake.info`

How do I disable the docs during configure?

---

Here is the configuration information for Automake 1.15.1:

```
$ ./configure --help
`configure' configures GNU Automake 1.15.1 to adapt to many kinds of systems.

Usage: ./configure [OPTION]... [VAR=VALUE]...

To assign environment variables (e.g., CC, CFLAGS...), specify them as
VAR=VALUE.  See below for descriptions of some of the useful variables.

Defaults for the options are specified in brackets.

Configuration:
  -h, --help              display this help and exit
      --help=short        display options specific to this package
      --help=recursive    display the short help of all the included packages
  -V, --version           display version information and exit
  -q, --quiet, --silent   do not print `checking ...' messages
      --cache-file=FILE   cache test results in FILE [disabled]
  -C, --config-cache      alias for `--cache-file=config.cache'
  -n, --no-create         do not create output files
      --srcdir=DIR        find the sources in DIR [configure dir or `..']

Installation directories:
  --prefix=PREFIX         install architecture-independent files in PREFIX
                          [/usr/local]
  --exec-prefix=EPREFIX   install architecture-dependent files in EPREFIX
                          [PREFIX]

By default, `make install' will install all the files in
`/usr/local/bin', `/usr/local/lib' etc.  You can specify
an installation prefix other than `/usr/local' using `--prefix',
for instance `--prefix=$HOME'.

For better control, use the options below.

Fine tuning of the installation directories:
  --bindir=DIR            user executables [EPREFIX/bin]
  --sbindir=DIR           system admin executables [EPREFIX/sbin]
  --libexecdir=DIR        program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]
  --sysconfdir=DIR        read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]
  --sharedstatedir=DIR    modifiable architecture-independent data [PREFIX/com]
  --localstatedir=DIR     modifiable single-machine data [PREFIX/var]
  --libdir=DIR            object code libraries [EPREFIX/lib]
  --includedir=DIR        C header files [PREFIX/include]
  --oldincludedir=DIR     C header files for non-gcc [/usr/include]
  --datarootdir=DIR       read-only arch.-independent data root [PREFIX/share]
  --datadir=DIR           read-only architecture-independent data [DATAROOTDIR]
  --infodir=DIR           info documentation [DATAROOTDIR/info]
  --localedir=DIR         locale-dependent data [DATAROOTDIR/locale]
  --mandir=DIR            man documentation [DATAROOTDIR/man]
  --docdir=DIR            documentation root [DATAROOTDIR/doc/automake]
  --htmldir=DIR           html documentation [DOCDIR]
  --dvidir=DIR            dvi documentation [DOCDIR]
  --pdfdir=DIR            pdf documentation [DOCDIR]
  --psdir=DIR             ps documentation [DOCDIR]

Program names:
  --program-prefix=PREFIX            prepend PREFIX to installed program names
  --program-suffix=SUFFIX            append SUFFIX to installed program names
  --program-transform-name=PROGRAM   run sed PROGRAM on installed program names

System types:
  --build=BUILD     configure for building on BUILD [guessed]
  --host=HOST       cross-compile to build programs to run on HOST [BUILD]

Optional Features:
  --disable-option-checking  ignore unrecognized --enable/--with options
  --disable-FEATURE       do not include FEATURE (same as --enable-FEATURE=no)
  --enable-FEATURE[=ARG]  include FEATURE [ARG=yes]
  --enable-silent-rules   less verbose build output (undo: "make V=1")
  --disable-silent-rules  verbose build output (undo: "make V=0")

Some influential environment variables:
  AM_TEST_RUNNER_SHELL
              a sturdy POSIX shell for our testsuite
  CC          C compiler command
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
              you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  CXX         C++ compiler command
  CXXFLAGS    C++ compiler flags
  FC          Fortran compiler command
  FCFLAGS     Fortran compiler flags
  F77         Fortran 77 compiler command
  FFLAGS      Fortran 77 compiler flags
  GNU_CC      GNU C compiler
  GNU_CFLAGS  GNU C compiler flags
  GNU_CXX     GNU C++ compiler
  GNU_CXXFLAGS
              GNU C++ compiler flags
  GNU_FC      GNU Fortran compiler
  GNU_FCFLAGS GNU Fortran compiler flags
  GNU_F77     GNU Fortran 77 compiler
  GNU_FFLAGS  GNU Fortran 77 compiler flags
  GNU_GCJ     GNU Java compiler
  GNU_GCJFLAGS
              GNU Java compiler flags

Use these variables to override the choices made by `configure' or to help
it to find libraries and programs with nonstandard names/locations.

Report bugs to <bug-automake@gnu.org>.
GNU Automake home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/>.
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
```

Comment: Just install package 'texinfo'. https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/texinfo/

Comment: This is frustrating me too, I cannot install texinfo, because texinfo is compatible with the tex documentation for this version of the compiler I have to use, which is what's breaking the documentation in the first place - this is exactly why this needs to be disabled, not "fixed".

Comment: @Owl - I found the answer below but it is project dependent. Some projects can be tricked with `MAKEINFO = true` while others avoid the variable and hard-code `makeinfo`. Those which hard code uses of `makeinfo` cannot be tricked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way seems to be to set `MAKEINFO = true` in the makefile:

```
$ cat automake-1.15.1/Makefile | grep '^MAKEINFO ='
MAKEINFO = ${SHELL} /home/scripts/automake-1.15.1/lib/missing makeinfo
```

Something like the following after configuring:

```
./configure --prefix="$INSTALL_PREFIX" --libdir="$INSTALL_LIBDIR"

sed -e 's|^MAKEINFO =*|MAKEINFO = true|g' Makefile > Makefile.fixed
mv Makefile.fixed Makefile
```

Comment: Off topic, better suited to linux/unix or superuser. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions

Comment: @123 downvoting is fine. But how is the question or this answer off-topic for StackOverflow? ...

Comment: Certainly on topic, it is a "a specific programming problem". And it was the first answer to mention the override. It needs more upvotes.

Answer (score 22):

Instead of editing files, when I run make I pass the argument MAKEINFO

```
make MAKEINFO=true
```

It might not be obvious at first glance what this does.

It overrides the MAKEINFO variable predefined by GNU make, which normally *points to the program to call* in order to get makeinfo invoked. So by setting it to `true` you are effectively replacing calls to `makeinfo` by calls to `/bin/true`. This changes the `makeinfo` tasks into no-op actions that always succeed, thus allowing the whole build to succeed, rather than halting at `makeinfo` errors.

Comment: One minor point about this. I think it should be pointed out what this does. It basically overrides the `MAKEINFO` variable predefined by GNU make, which normally points to the _program_ to call in order to get `makeinfo` invoked. So by setting it to `true` you are effectively replacing calls to `makeinfo` by calls to `/bin/true` (can be seen with `make -npf /dev/null |grep ^MAKEINFO`).

Comment: The root cause, and the exact problem I had was an old system that makeinfo could not be installed on.  I wrote this solution because it does not require editing the auto generated makefile, nor does require adding a makeinfo program to the PATH.

Comment: your solution is sound. If you read my comment you will have noticed that the only thing I bemoan is that - as simple as this solution is - your answer does not at all _explain_ the mechanism. Because setting a variable in itself doesn't explain anything whatsoever. Explaining that it leads to execution of `true` in place of `makeinfo` is a much clearer explanation.

Answer (score 7):

You can non-intrusively prevent building by making `makeinfo` a no-op. The easiest way so far I've found is to symlink a local `makeinfo` to `true` before building so that `configure` and `make` find that instead. I.e. you can do this:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/true makeinfo
export PATH=${PWD}:${PATH}
```

Comment: I've done this manipulation of the precedence of `PATH` many times over in order to bend legacy build systems to my will. Very good point. Does the same like the `MAKEINFO=true` trick, but will even work when the invocation of `makeinfo` doesn't happen via the `MAKEINFO` variable.

Answer (score -2):

you can change "missing" file, and direct exit 0